# Craft sometimes takes several minutes to respond to a request

Tags: server

I have a pretty simple Craft site running a Digital Ocean Ubuntu droplet and for some reason it can sometimes take several minutes to save an entry.

I think this might be something to do with sessions as, when it happens, the site stops responding completely for that browser unless I quit and re-open it. Whilst it is happening, accessing the website via another browser works fine. There's nothing in the phperrors.log or the craft.log that even relate to the time the problem happens but there's something in the Application Logs that seem relevant.

Here's a sample of the 'Profiling Summary Report' where you can see it took 300s to respond but none of the queries takes anything other than milliseconds: http://pastebin.com/pbf7bj2e

The interesting bit is is the Application Log where you can see the timestamps jump from 13:00 to 13:05 on line 58:

http://pastebin.com/gdCgTUSC

What is happening there that took 5 minutes?

Comment: Does it only saving an entry? What about when saving a global? Does this happen in devMode or out of devMode? Does the rest of the CP seem to run ok? Did it always happen on this site or did it start occurring at a certain point? It might also be worth opening a support ticket with P&T on this.

Comment: You're on to something with the devMode thing. I forgot to mention it works fine if I access the site via its IP address. I hadn't considered the fact that this would, due to the site config, not run the site in devMode as its a development version still in production. It does indeed work fine when not in devMode.

Comment: Yes, I would enter that support ticket. There's a smell here about possibly not explicitly flushing last output - seemingly the invisible DevMode logging you can find at the end of your html view source. Combined with some mystery DO php task commuting if so...

Answer (score 2):

I have had this same experience many times, but only with certain hosting providers, so I suspect it has something to do with server configuration.  One thing that I noticed was that saving an entry, for example, would hang, but the entry had indeed been saved pretty much immediately.

I know it is not my local setup, because my co worked, who works from a different location, had the same issues at the same time.  Next time it happens I will try accessing via IP.